# ReactJS Scroll element a set amount of pixals

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll

How do I Scroll an element (not the entire page) a specific amount of pixals for example 100px on every click of a button (not a has link because it needs to be a fixed amount of pixals each time) I use ReactJS 16.

Comment: Would [scrollBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollBy` on the element you want to scroll. A vanilla JS example:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let box = document.getElementById('box');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.scrollBy({top:100, behavior: "smooth"});
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#inner-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}
.content {
  height: 50px;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">scroll</button>
<div id="box">
  <div id="inner-box">
    <div class="content">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a ReactJS version:

```
class Scrollable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.scroll = this.scroll.bind(this);
    this.box = React.createRef();
  }

  scroll() {
    this.box.current.scrollBy({top:100, behavior: "smooth"});
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.scroll}>scroll</button>
      <div id="box" ref={this.box}>
        <div id="inner-box">
          <div class="content">
          content
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          content
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          content
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          content
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          content
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLXzmx?editors=0010)